# Groovy rootLoader is null

Tags: groovy, classloader

When running a groovy script from Eclipse, the following line:

```
def rootLoader = this.class.getClassLoader().getRootLoader()
```

is null. When I run the script directly from command line, this is not null. How can I find out why this happens?

Comment: what version of eclipse? what version of the groovy plugin?
does your project have a groovy nature?

Answer (score 1):

It depends on how you to start groovy script.

If you run (without 'groovy' command):

```
java -cp lib/groovy-all-1.7.5.jar groovy.ui.GroovyMain YourGroovyScript.groovy
```

Script is run, but rootLoader is null.

If you want to use rootLoader, run script with this command line:

```
java -cp lib/groovy-all-1.7.5.jar org.codehaus.groovy.tools.GroovyStarter --classpath lib/groovy-all-1.7.5.jar --main groovy.ui.GroovyMain YourGroovyScript.groovy
```

Comment: As part of Jenkins ActiveChoices plugin.  I need to load the TFS API jar to connect to TFS.  How can this be done?